# Story where a character would properly close their eyes after closing their eyelids

Tags: story-identification

Today I suddenly remembered a moment from a story that I read probably around 2007 where a character described that people only close their eyelids but not their eyes and thus see only absence of light and not the darkness. After that another character closed *their eyes* and was able to see the darkness and the story progressed.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved if you went through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: This made me think of the instruction given to Tiffany Aching in ["The Wee Free Men"](https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/62580-the-wee-free-men), to "Open your eyes and then open your eyes again.". I mention it because sometimes we remember things back to front.

Comment: Mentioning Pratchett makes me wonder if I'm correct in recalling a scene where Commander Vimes uses the Summoning Dark to see in pitch blackness...